# Retrieving a list variable in Apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Question**

How can I access the value of a field in a list of custom objects?

**Background**

I have a code that uses the user email input to find out if the user exists and if the user is qualified or not based on the `Qualified__c` field of a custom object `Inquery__c`.  When I query the I get back a list, but I don't know how to get the value out.  What do I need to do?

Here is a snippet from my class:

```
   usersList = New List<Inquery__c>();
   usersList  = [select Quilification__c,email__c from Inquery__c where email__c=:EnteredEmail ];
   if(usersList.size()>0){
      if(usersList.Quilification__c == 'Qualified') { 
        // user is qualified
      } else {
        // user not qualified
      }
   } else {
      // user not found
   }
```

This line is given me an error

```
if(usersList.Quilification__c == 'Qualified')
```

Comment: Thanks for coming on board at SFSE! One benefit of doing this in an online forum is the answer you get can also help the next person.  To make the question as useful as possible it's helpful to narrow down your question to the specific issue at hand instead of posting the entire piece of code.  This can help avoid having people close your question as too localized.

Comment: Some other tips, you don't need to initialize usersList if you're going to query it on the next line (you can just assign it directly).  Also, you might think about what you're code should be doing if the query returns more than one record that matches a given email.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I will be more specific next time,

Comment: Sometimes the full code can also be helpful.  In those cases you might upload the full into a [gist](http://gist.github.com) and then post a link below the snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists themselves don't have fields, just the object's in them.  You need to either pull a specific object out or iterate over the list.

**Extract Object**

```
Inquery__c record = userList[0];
if(record.qualification__c == 'Qualified') {
  // do something
```

**Loop**

```
for(Inquery__c record : usersList) {
  if(record.qualification__c == 'Qualified') {
    // do something
```

If you're only expecting to have one object you can utilize the fact single record queries can be assigned directly to an object instead of a list

```
Inquery__c record = [select ... from Inquery__c limit 1];
```

One downside to this approach is an exception is thrown if there are no records returned.  One method would be to assign in a loop.

```
Inquery__c obj;
for(Inquery__c record : [select ... from Inquery__c limit 1]) {
  obj = record;
}
if(obj == null) {
  // user not found, do something
} else if(obj.qualified__c == 'Qualified') {
  // do something else
```